# Shaded view shows extra surface?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm new to Blender and Geometry Nodes. In the images below, the wireframe one looks correct, but the shaded one does not: it has a "surface" inside the crater that isn't expected.

Any ideas where this is coming from?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just switch the *Fill Type* of the cone fron *N-Gon* to *None*.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As @quellenform said, it's the fill type causing the issue.